# Type of Variable Changes When Loading Data From Mat File at Matlab

Tags: file, matlab, variables

I have a variable at Matlab it is a:

```
<2196x1 cell>
```

I save it as like:

```
save('var.mat','var');
```

I read it with load but the variable I have is:

```
<1x1 struct>
```

How can I read it from file as a cell vector again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that if you use

```
x = load('var.mat')
```

you end up with a 1x1 struct, where `x.var` is the original, saved variable.  To get back the original variables, as you saved them, try using

```
load('var.mat');  %No output argument
```

This will put to original variables back into the workspace.

This behavior allows you to load multiple variables with the same name (e.g. `x.var` and `y.var`), should that ever be required.